# Awk statement in bash isn't executing when in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk

I have a text file with search terms (patts) that I need to delete from 'patterns.txt'. I have tested out the awk statement and it works correctly - except in the script.

Also, the $target variable is printing correctly when I echo to standard output. For some reason, however, the statement isn't executing properly.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

input_file='patts'
i=0
while read line; do
  array[$i]=$line
  i=$((i+1))
done < "$input_file"
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
  target=`eval echo ${array[i]}`
  echo $target
  awk '!/$target/' patterns.txt > temp && mv temp patterns.txt
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell variables don't expand in single quotes. Also it is better to use `-v name=value` to pass arguments to awk:

```
awk -v target="$target" '!($0 ~ target)' patterns.txt > temp && mv temp patterns.txt
```

**However it looks like you can use replace `awk` by `grep -v`:**

```
grep -v "$target" patterns.txt > temp && mv temp patterns.txt
```

Comment: It returns "awk: non-terminated regular expression ($0 ~ $tar... at source line 1
 context is
  >>>  <<<"

Comment: Why are you using `$target`, did you not see my answer?

Comment: Does the same thing when I use $0 ~ target

Comment: grep statement worked. But it needs to be exact search string. If I have Bob as a search term it will kill Bobby also.

Comment: `grep` behaves same as `awk` and both are performing regex. If you want fixed string search: `grep -Fv "$target" patterns.txt > temp && mv temp patterns.txt`

Comment: grep -Fv will not prevent a search criteria of "BobBob" from being deleted if the search term is "Bob"

Comment: Switch is actually -x and not -F

Comment: `-x` for exact match and `-F` is for fixed string match that's what I wrote above.